# "began to ring" or "started ringing"?

Tags: meaning

What is more correct here?

> My telephone suddenly began to ring.

or

> My telephone suddenly started ringing.

What's the difference?

Comment: There's no significant difference between these two stylistic choices - or indeed, the other two *("began ringing"*, and *"started to ring")*.

Comment: As per @FrozenFyr, it would be 'start', not 'begin', since you say 'suddenly'.

Comment: I can't tell if this question is about the difference between *start* and *begin*, or about whether or not to include the preposition *to* when the telephone starts to ring, or the doorbell starts ringing.

Comment: @J.R. - When I was asking this question, I didn't know that it was permissible to say "began V-ing" or "started to INFINITIVE", so my question is simply about "began to INF" and "started V-ing", precisely, which one of them is correct in the mentioned context.

Comment: The _to_ in the sentence is not actually a preposition. It is rather part of the infinitive _to ring_.

Comment: @SigueSigueBen - I was also going to say that. To me it looks more like a particle. To be on the safe side, I would just refer to it generally as a "function word", but, strangely, Webster places it in the category of prepositions.

Comment: @SigueSigueBen: Oops! Thanks for the correction... I'd go back and edit if I could...

Comment: @brilliant: okay, thanks... much of discussion seemed to focus on _start_ vs _begin_, but I wasn't sure that's what you were really asking about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an article from: http://www.english-test.net/articles/24/index.html (Author: Alex Townend). He explains the difference between "start" and "begin".

> Where shall we start? Where shall we begin? Shall we begin at the start, start at the beginning, start at the start or even begin at the beginning? That last one was good enough for the Welsh poet, Dylan Thomas in his famous play for voices, Under Milk Wood first broadcast in February 1954 a few weeks after the poet's death. The actor Richard Burton intoned the lines: «To begin at the beginning: It is spring, moonless night in the small town, starless and bible-black…» The two verbs «start» and «begin» are like so many couples in the English language a really troublesome pair because of the problem of choosing the right one for the appropriate use and occasion. Take these two sentences for example:
>
> «I've started to learn English and I've begun to learn English». Which one would you choose? Well, I have a theory about these verbs which I want to try out in order to test its validity. The difference really lies in the nature of the two words. «Begin» has a sense of leisure and «start» has the idea of urgency. They both obviously indicate the idea of commencing — don't ask me to explain that word's relationship with the pair, suffice it to say that it covers both meanings — but there is a difference in interpretation. «Start» gives the idea of suddenness. In fact if you were sitting in a room and say half asleep and you were unaware that there was anybody else there, you would say if you unexpectedly heard or saw them:
>
> «Oh, you did give me a start» or as an extension of the verb: «You startled me». Then again you could say: «My car starts straightaway in the morning». If you said: «My car begins in the morning», people would wonder what it was going to do next. As a further use you could look at the English translation of the Bible and go to the New Testament John 1:1, to read:
>
> «In the beginning was the word and the word was with God and the word was God». It would be ludicrous here to use the word «start». If you want to get on with a meeting because nobody is paying attention, you might say:
>
> «Shall we start?» And thus indicate that there is a lot to do and time is important. «Shall we begin?» is much more relaxed. There is a sort of uniqueness in idea behind the verb «start» as if it hasn't happened before, take these two sentences for example:
>
> «Charlie (baby) started speaking at the age of two and Charlie (chairman) began speaking at two o'clock». Back to my original question concerning the learning of English. «I've started to learn English» suggests possibly «I have to for my job» or «I've thought about it for a long time and now decided the time is right». Whereas «I've begun to learn English» gives the idea that you've taken up this as a hobby and it might be of interest to other people.
>
> If you had to give the two verbs a personality, you might well describe start as «impetuous, decisive and efficient». Begin can perhaps be described as «relaxed, unhurried and good-natured».

Comment: +1 Very convincing theory. Have you published this in a peer reviewed journal? You should, I'm sure.

Comment: However, you forgot to answer the Q. Or left it as implied/ too obvious.

Comment: @Kris: I was writing another answer (see below), where i could quote a few references and the exact situations where only 'start' is possible. Cheers!! I don't know how to publish in a "peer reviewed journal", can you help?

Comment: At the beginning of other answer, i suggested that the answers from other people on brilliant's case are correct. I just didn't pay much attention to answering his case because others did it very well already, only that they mistook 'start' and 'begin' as interchangeable in every situation.

Comment: I agree with Kris. I think your theory is very convincing. Thank you.

Comment: It *sounds* like a good theory but  I'm not sure I believe it.  They've begun the countdown for liftoff. The baby began to cry. The leaves have started to turn.  These usages sound natural to me yet, the sense of urgency/leisure is opposite that of the theory.

Comment: The author has cherry-picked some examples to support his theory which doesn't reflect how English speakers actually use the English language.

Comment: @SigueSigueBen: you may want to check the other answer I posted below where i mentioned the instances (and examples) where use of 'start' is not correct. Moreover, the "cherry-picked" examples in the above post are not uncommon in English. To prove a theory, examples are needed. If they fit perfectly, the theory is proved beyond doubt. Cheers!!

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr The instances where _begin_ is not permissible have nothing to do with the author's theory (although he tries to shoehorn them into it). Moreover, the suggestion that English speakers prefer _start_ when the action hasn't happened before or occurs suddenly is weak at best.

Answer (score 1):

In general the verbs `start` and `begin` are synonyms. Note that you can use a gerund or an infinitive after both verbs, so the following two sentences are also valid:

> My telephone suddenly began ringing.
>
> My telephone suddenly started to ring.

Comment: So that means it is correct to say "I begin/began a car." or "I begin/began the machine." or "I begin/began my computer." I don't think so. There is a difference between the words(else, no reason for having two separate words), they are synonyms but they can't be used interchangeably in every case, though it is alright in the given example.

Comment: @brilliant: As advised to me by another contributor, it's always a better practice to wait for at least a day or two before you mark your question as "answered". You may get better answers. Consider voting the answers you get till then.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr Read the question and answer very carefully. The question is: "What is more correct **here**?" My answer states "**In general** they are synonyms."

Answer (score 1):

According to most people (and dictionaries), 'start' and 'begin' are synonyms and are interchangeable, as in the case of your example. Since nobody mentioned this, I thought there is a need to cite a few cases where they stand different.

However, according to **The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language**, *only **start**, not begin, can imply setting out from a specific point, frequently following inaction*. It also notes that ***begin*** often means to take the first step in performing or to come into being.

> Stand here and visit with me for a few minutes until the train starts.

**Michael Swan (Practical English Usage, 2nd ed., Oxford University Press, 1995)** lists these instances in which ***start***, but **NOT** ***begin***, is used:

> 1. start a journey: 
>      I think we ought to start at six, while the roads are empty.
> 2. start working (for machines):
>      The car won’t start.
> 3. make (machines) start:
>      How do you start the washing machine?”

It may be concluded from cases described above that, while ***start*** and ***begin*** can be interchanged in most cases like your example, only ***start*** is possible here.

*Reference: Pearson Education*

Answer (score -1):

In situations like this I tend to go for a more proper tense. It seems as though this sentence is past tense so I would use this variation:

> My telephone suddenly rang.

The extra words `began` or `started` are unnecessary and if you use `ringing` that indicates to me present tense whereas `began` and `started` are both past tense.

Comment: The `ringing` in `My telephone started ringing` has nothing to do with tense and does not suggest that the action is happening at present. It is a gerund and is functionally a noun, not a verb.

Comment: It has to do with the tense in that my example uses `past simple` which is the most common form when referring to an action that was completed in the past. The OP is using `past continuous` which emphasizes the continuity of the action. Not that his method is incorrect grammatically it's merely a style choice and also depends on what he is trying to imply. Personally I just prefer more concise writing.

Comment: Past continuous is something like _The phone was ringing_. There is nothing wrong with using a gerund as the object (or subject) of a verb which is in a past (or future) tense. For example, you can't say that _I enjoyed meeting you yesterday_ is wrong in any way.